# How can I add a default to my CSS slide show banner?

Tags: css, image, slider, default

I used a free CSS slideshow I found on line and edited it, and I can't figure out how to add a default image. I created a fiddle to show my code: [[link]](http://jsfiddle.net/tdU3Q/)

Also, in the code, the:

```
<img id="imageX" src="images/banners/X.png">
```

Does have an image show up. I'd show you but it's run on my localhost.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you by mean saying "how to add a default image." ?

Comment: I meant by default image that when you visit the page this is located, it will show up without the URL having to have the #image1 on the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing what you mean as a problem, is that when the slider is loaded `img` elements have `opacity:0; left:-400px; z-index:1;` and you only set

```
  #homebanner img:first-child {
     left: 0;
  }
```

so it does not display the first image at first, but you could do something like this instead

```
  #homebanner img:first-child {
     left: 0;
     z-index: 9;
     opacity: 1;
  }
```

(mostly the opacity here), to immediately display it.

This way the image also stays as a "default"/background image between the slide switching.

Here I also updated your fiddle and I added some random images for illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/tdU3Q/3/